# generic constructor in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following:

```
GenericClass<T> : Class
{
  T Results {get; protected set;}
  public GenericClass<T> (T results, Int32 id) : base (id)
  {
    Results=results;
  }
  public static GenericClass<T> Something (Int32 id)
  {
   return new GenericClass<T> (i need to pass something like new T?, id); 
  }
}
```

Update T can be either type or value, so using new() is okish for some types but definetely not for values. I suppose that would imply some class redesign.

the idea was how to use the constructor? eg is it possible to pass something similar to new T (although it should not, because T is not known at the time) or what will to be the twist to avoid passing null?

Comment: Not stupid at all. You should see **some** of the questions posted here >;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class GenericClass<T> : Class where T : new()
{
  public T Results {get; protected set;}
  public GenericClass (T results, Int32 id) : base (id)
  {
    Results=results;
  }
  public static GenericClass<T> Something (Int32 id)
  {
   return new GenericClass<T> (new T(), id); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
GenericClass<T> : Class where T : new()
{
  T Results {get; protected set;}
  public GenericClass<T> (T results, Int32 id)
  {
    Results=results;
  }
  public GenericClass<T> Something (Int32 id) : this(new T(), id)
  { }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say, you beat me to it. To the OP, basically you just need to restrict T to classes that have a known public constructor (here, the default constructor).

Answer (score 0):

How about using reflection?

```
public static GenericClass<T> Something (Int32 id)
  {
   return new GenericClass<T> ((T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)), id); 
  }
```

Comment: WAY over the top, and though this compiles it would still fail at runtime if T didn't have a public parameterless constructor.